# Base Conversion: Question on common algorithm using Euclidean division

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algorithms, euclidean-algorithm

I can see that this algorithm converts bases, however have questions on whats actually going on.  The algorithm is presented, then questions follow.

**Algorithm**

To convert a number $X$ to base $B$.

1. $k = 1$

   $X \bmod B = R_k$,
   $Q = \frac {X - R_k} B$

where $\bmod$ is defined:
$q \in \mathbb{Z}, r = X - Bq, |r| < |B|$

2. $(Q = 0) \implies$ Goto #3

   $(Q \ne 0) \implies (X = Q) \land (k = k + 1) \land $ Goto #1
3. Converted string is $R_n, ..., R_1$

What is happening mathematically that $R_k$, the remainders, correspond to the converted numbers digits?  What significance is there to dividing by the new quotient $X = Q$ each iteration?

I have seen this algorithm a few times, however have yet to see a detailed mathematical explanation on why it works.

Comment: Hint for $k=1$: $X=(R_nB^{n-1}+\ldots+R_2B)+R_1=S_1B+R_1$ where $S_1=(X-R_1)/B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

${a_ma_{m-1}a_{m-1}a_{m-3}....a_3a_2a_1a_0}_b = a_mb^m + a_{m-1}b^{m-1} + a_{m-2}b^{m-2}+a_{m-3}b^{m-3}+......+a_3b^3 + a_2b^2 + a_1b + a_0=$

$b(a_mb^{m-1} + a_{m-1}b^{m-2}+ a_{m-2}b^{m-3}+........ + a_3b^2 + a_2b + a_1) + a_0 =$

$b^(b(a_mb^{m-2} + a_{m-1}b^{m-3} + a_{m-3}b^{m-4}+.......+ a_3b + a_2) + a_1) + a_0 = $

$b(b(b(a_mb^{m-1} + a_{m-1}b^{m-4} + a_{m-3}b^{m-5}+.......+ a_3) + a_2) + a_1) + a_0 =$

$.....$

$b(b(....(a_mb^2 + a_{m-1}b + a_{m-2}) + a_{m-3} + ....... + a_3) + a_2) + a_1) + a_0=$

$b(b(b(....(a_mb + a_{m-1}) + a_{m-2}) + a_{m-3} + ....... + a_3) + a_2) + a_1) + a_0=$

So each of the $a_k$ digit is the result of taking a remainder when dividing by $b$.